# Best way to remove twitter user names from list of tweets?

Tags: python, string, split, data-cleaning

I am trying to find the best way to remove twitter usernames from a users tweet if there is a username present in the tweet. For example I have an array of stored tweets and I would like to return the tweet with the username taken out like this

```
tweets = ['@joe123 thank you', 'this reminds me of @john12', 'this tweet has no username tag in it']

clean_tweets = ['thank you', 'this reminds me of', 'this tweet has no username tag in it']
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
tweets = ['@joe123 thank you', 'this reminds me of @john12', 'this tweet has no username tag in it']

clean_tweets = [word for tweet in tweets for word in tweet.split() if not word.startswith('@')]
```

However output looks like this:

```
['thank',
 'you',
 'this',
 'reminds',
 'me',
 'of',
 'this',
 'tweet',
 'has',
 'no',
 'username',
 'tag',
 'in',
 'it']
```

I am hoping for a better way to solve this other than using nested list comprehension. Maybe an apply function with lambda will work better? Anything helps thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways. Say, use regular expressions: replace a @ followed by at least one alphanumeric symbol, with an empty string.

```
import re
[re.sub(r'@\w+', '', x) for x in tweets]
#['thank you', 'this reminds me of', 'this tweet has no username tag in it']
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any way to remove the extra spaces with one regex? I thought of `r' ?@\w+ ?'` but while it would handle it sometimes, often it would remove too many. I suppose you could`r'@\w+'` to remove the mention and then change double spaces to single spaces, but can it be done in one statement?

Comment: Updated to remove spaces.

Comment: The problem with that is with a string like "hey @mention what's up" you get "heywhat's up" - that's what I meant by it removing too many spaces.

Comment: @thshea Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try this list comprehension:

`clean_tweets = [" ".join([word for word in tweet.split() if not word.startswith('@')]) for tweet in tweets]`

`[word for word in tweet.split() if not word.startswith('@')]` - given a tweet, split it into words, and then return a list of the words that are not mentions

`" ".join()` - Turn that list back into a string

`[... for tweet in tweets]` - Do this for every tweet